# Checking time was within past 24 hours in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, referrals

I have developed a referral system where logged in members can send referrals to there family/friends to recommend them to sign up.

Everything works fine but yesterday decided I would limit the maximum referrals someone could send within a 24 hour period. I have limited this to 3 referrals maximum per day.

I posted the bit of code that I seem to be having problems with below. The problem I am having is that no matter what it seems I get the error message saying I have reach the maximum referrals for today. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in my code.

```
// referral query
$referral_limit = mysql_query("SELECT 'created_on' FROM 'user_referrals'
WHERE `referrer_uid` = $referrer_uid ") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($referral_limit) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($referral_limit)){

            $db_time = $row['created_on'];

            if((time() - $db_time) > 86400){
                // is within 24 hours and has reached maximum daily referral allowance
                $error[] = "You have reached the maximum referrals for today.";
            }
    }
}
```

I did try and echo out $db_time and when I do all I get returned is the field name which is **created_on** and not the actual value which in this case should display the timestamp. The **created_on** field in database contains the timestamp a referral was made and I check this to ensure the referring user has not made a referral within the past 24 hours.

You will also notice I have not added the extra bit that restricts it to 3 per day but I did not want to add that bit until I can fix this problem first.

The database table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_referrals` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`referrer_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`recipient_username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`referrer_email` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
`referred_id` char(32) NOT NULL,
`referred_email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
`status` char(9) NOT NULL,
`created_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
`updated_on` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `referred_id` (`referred_id`),
KEY `referrer_uid` (`referrer_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=72 ;
```

### Edit

Here is my code after some assistance. It still says a referral was made in past 24 hours even though there isn't.

I think I am doing the error checking wrong.

```
$referral_limit = mysql_query("
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM `user_referrals`
        WHERE `referrer_uid` = $referrer_uid
        AND `created_on` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))") or die(mysql_error());

if($referral_limit > 0) {
    $error[] = "You have reached the maximum referrals for today.";
}
```

Comment: `created_on` and `updated_on` can be `date` instead of `int`

Comment: hi, i store the timestamp as an int as i prefer to use php time() and do conversions etc in php code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do NOT EVER filter the full MySQL result set in PHP when you can also filter it in MySQL. In your code example, you fetch maybe thousands of rows from MySQL only to run them through your filtering loop. This is the hardest performance killer ever. Rather use a better SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'referrals' WHERE `referrer_uid`=? AND created_on > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

This statement just returns the count (!) of referals of the given referer in the last 24 hours.

Besides, you should never insert variables directly into MySQL like `WHERE name=$name`, this opens your application to a myriad of SQL injection attacks. If you do not know what sql injection is, you should learn it right now.

Comment: the query is protected from sql injection etc just not shown full code. Also the fields that stores the php unix timestamp are int fields as i am not familiar with mysql date/time functions plus they don't store them as unix timestamps which i prefer.

Comment: Hi Steffen, i have to pop out but will give your code a try later and vote up etc. Thanks for your reply and time much appreciated.

Comment: I have edited my code but not sure how i check that a referral was made within past 24 hours because i am not familiar with those mysql functions. I have tried but can't seem to get it to work. Would it be possible if you could give me an example how i would check if a referral was made within past 24 hours ? for some reason the query seems to work fine but i don't know how to check if referral was made in past 24 hours using the code i have. Thanks

Comment: Hi PHPLover, I'm afraid I do not understand your question? The query returns the count of referals from the given referrer in the last 24 hours. If you are not familiar with the MySQL functions used, just have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html.

Concerning your current code, you must remove the quotes around created_on in your SQL statement. With the quotes, MySQL does not use it as a column name but just as a string.

Comment: maybe that's why it's not working, although you say it returns the count of referrals in the last 24 hours, does that mean i just need to check to ensure that the count is not greater than 0 ? by that i mean if the count result returned is greater than 0 then a referral was made in past 24 hours. Thanks

Comment: Exactly, thats the point of the query. Just check if the number returned is > 0, because than a referral was made in the last 24 hours.

Comment: i updated my original post with the code i am now using to do the check. Would you mind looking at it as it still shows error that i made a referral in past 24 hours although i haven't. I think i am doing the error checking wrong. Sorry for seeming dumb on this. Thanks phplover

Comment: Your code is wrong. The result of mysql_query is always a result handler to the resultset which is never 0. You have to use the return value of mysql_query to fetch the result with something like mysql_fetch_row. In the resultset, you will find the number you want to compare.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use MySQL to calculate that:

```
$referral_limit = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*)
                               FROM referrals
                               WHERE referrer_uid = $referrer_uid
                               AND created_on >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                              ") or die(mysql_error());
```

provided that `created_on` is a `datetime` or a `timestamp`. Why is it declared `INT` ?

Comment: Hi, i replied to two comments above regarding using INT instead of datetime. Thanks

Comment: @PHPLOVER: See Steffen's answer which has the check working with your int datatype.

Comment: Thanks ypercube, I have to pop out but will check Steffen's answer later etc. Thanks for all the replies everyone much appreciated as always.

Comment: @PHPLOVER: Try this query with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on) - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Answer (score 1):

Do not put single quotes around the fieldname you are selecting, since this will be interpreted as a string to return.  E.g. you need

```
SELECT created_on ...
```

(unless you've actually got backticks in your code and the included code in your example is incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
$referral_limit = mysql_query("SELECT `created_on` FROM `referrals`
 WHERE `referrer_uid` = $referrer_uid ") or die(mysql_error());
```

That is backticks for created_on and not quotes. If you use quotes, the field becomes a string, similar to `SELECT 1 FROM table` which returns 1

Comment: Hi, I noticed my problem and it now echos out correctly. Problem i got is that even thou i just made a referral to test and that it is within past 24 hours it still allows me to make more than one referral. At the moment as the code currnetly stands it should not allow me to make more than one referral as i just made a referral so it should return the error message to say i already made a referral within past 24 hours. :/ Thanks

Comment: @PHPLOVER: I think the logic u r using is wrong. Shoudlnt it be `((time() - $db_time) < 86400)`, ie if the referral created is less then 24 hours it is an error???

Comment: hi i want it so it a referral has already been created less than 24 hours ago then return the error. I seem to have confused myself quite a bit. I have replied to Steffan's post as his query works but having a tiny problem with the validating part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`created_on` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `updated_on` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,

Surely these should be datetime fields?

Comment: Hi, i replied to two comments above regarding using INT instead of datetime. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change your query

```
$referral_limit = mysql_query("SELECT 'created_on' FROM 'user_referrals'WHERE `referrer_uid` = $referrer_uid ") or die(mysql_error());
```

to

```
$referral_limit = mysql_query("SELECT `created_on` FROM `user_referrals` WHERE `referrer_uid` = $referrer_uid ") or die(mysql_error());
```